# class="mytest anothertest"...what is anothertest?

Tags: html, css

Trying to learn html/css. I've been looking at the html & css files of a couple different websites that have something along the line of:

```
<span class="mytest anothertest">some text goes here</span>
```

I understand the "mytest" part but what does "anothertest" do? There's no reference to that anywhere in their css or html files.

Comment: It doesn't need to do anything. It's not mandatory to style all your class names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`anothertest` is just another [class](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssintermediate/classid/) like `mytest`. You can apply more than one to an element.

Comment: that's what I was thinking but guess the website I was looking at goofed and forgot to put "anothertest" in their css file. thx!

Comment: It doesn´t have to be that they forgot it, the classname may have been used for other purposes such as targeting all elements with that classname with javascript functions (maybe we can call that marker-classes?). In this day and age, classnames are used for both targeting elements with css and javascript and not always both.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible reasons for the presence of a class name in a class attribute value. Using the class in page stylesheets is probably most widely known, but not the only one:

- The class name can be used in JavaScript in order to process a set of elements conveniently. (Using document.getElementsByClass is one way to achieve this; another way is to use jQuery; and you could even hand-code it rather simply.)
- Designated class names are used in some metadata systems, such as microformats. Some search engines recognize such names and use them to provide semantic searching (though this approach probably loses to microdata, which uses different attributes).
- A class name can be used in a *user* style sheet, e.g. by a developer who wishes to do some testing. This could well be the case if the class name is literally “anothertest.”
- The name might be there to allow future development, e.g. so that elements of a class will be or may be styled in some future version. The designers might have ideas on styling but they haven’t decided on it—they just want it to be easy when they are ready.
- It could be just a holdover. It was a class that had some use, but things changed. There was really no particular reason to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Class name are also used to easily select elements in the page with JavaScript. You can use the [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) method to access them or using your favorite CSS selector library (ex.: Sizzle) if you need compatibility for older browser.

Comment: If supported by the browser (not in IE8 and below).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question. It involved the difference between `id` and `class`.

### ID

An ID placed on an element, is a unique identifier for that element. An element may only have one ID, and only one of the same ID may exist on a page. So for instance, the following examples are not possible.

```
<a id="someid anotherid">Multiple IDs - Wrong</a>
<a id="someid"><span id="someid">Same ID twice - Wrong</span></a>
```

### Class

A class name however, is the exact opposite. An element may have several class names, and the same class name may appear multiple times on a page. Like so:

```
<a class="someclass anotherclass">Multiple Classes - Correct</a>
<a class="someclass"><span class="someclass">Same Class twice - correct</span></a>
```

---

In short, the syntax displayed in the question is simply having 2 class names on one element, which is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: The question did not refer to id attributes at all, and the question implies rather than denies the possibility of multiple class names.